# Android updating Realm 5.12 to 5.15 throws exception

Tags: android, realm-mobile-platform

Recently I updated Realm plugin version 5.12 to 5.15.1, installing as a fresh app will work correctly but upgrading the old app that was using Realm 5.12.0 to 5.15 when the app launches it's throwing an exception even thought I did not change any of the database models. I'm using Synced Realm default configuration and this is the exception:

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following changes cannot be made in additive-only schema mode:
>
> - Property '__ResultSets.updated_at' has been made required.
> - Property '__ResultSets.updated_at' has been made required.

Does anybody is experiencing this problem.

Comment: Can you please show the code from application class? I want to show how you have init realm

Comment: your issue is regarding migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm team just updated the SDK and now the bug is fixed:

[#6619](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6619#event-2673100598)